# R - Twitter Extraction - Error in .subset2(x, i, exact=exact)

Tags: json, r, twitter, jsonlite

I am making an R-script to get all of the mentions (@username) of a specific set of users.

My first issue isn't a big deal. I try to work at home, as well as work. At work, the code works fine. At home, I get Error 32 - Could not authenticate you from Oauth.  This is using the exact same code, key, secret, token. I have tried resetting my secret key/token, same thing.  Not a problem, since I can do remote login, but its frustrating.

The **REAL** issue here...
I construct a URL (ex: final_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=@JimFKenney&until=2015-10-25&result_type=recent&count=100")

Then I search twitter for my query of @usernameDesired to get all the comments where they were mentioned.

```
   mentions = GET(final_url, sig)
```

This works fine, but then I want my data in a usable format so I do...

```
   library(rjson)
   #install.packages("jsonlite", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
   library(jsonlite)
   #install.packages("bit64", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
   json = content(mentions)
```

I then get the following error -

```
   $statuses
   Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

I don't have even the first idea of what can be causing this.

Any help is gratly appreciated.

EDIT 1: For Clarity, I get the error when trying to see what is in json. If I do "json = content(mentions)" that line of code executes fine.  I then type "json" to see what is in the variable, and I get the above error that starts with $statuses.